# Guava BloomFilter - Error in Scala compiler: trying to do lub/glb of typevar ?T

Tags: scala, sbt

Using scala 2.11.8, guava 20.0 and sbt 0.13.13, 
the following snippet causes the compile to crash:

```
import com.google.common.hash.BloomFilter
object Test {
  def test() {
    BloomFilter.create(null, 1, 1)
  }
}
```

with the error:

> Error in Scala compiler: trying to do lub/glb of typevar ?T
>   SBT builder crashed while compiling. The error message is 'trying to do lub/glb of typevar ?T'
>   Unknown   Scala Problem

Any idea what causes this problem?

The full log:

> [error] trying to do lub/glb of typevar ?T
>   scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: trying to do lub/glb of typevar ?T
>     at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting$class.abort(Reporting.scala:59)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:16)   at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.GlbLubs$class.stripType$1(GlbLubs.scala:224)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.GlbLubs$$anonfun$18.apply(GlbLubs.scala:227)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.GlbLubs$$anonfun$18.apply(GlbLubs.scala:227)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)   at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.GlbLubs$class.stripExistentialsAndTypeVars(GlbLubs.scala:227)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.GlbLubs$class.lub1$1(GlbLubs.scala:328)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.GlbLubs$class.lub0$1(GlbLubs.scala:322)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.GlbLubs$class.lub(GlbLubs.scala:419)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.lub(SymbolTable.scala:16)     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.GlbLubs$class.lub(GlbLubs.scala:279)   at
>   scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.lub(SymbolTable.scala:16)  at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$class.solveOne$1(TypeConstraints.scala:248)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$$anonfun$solve$1.apply(TypeConstraints.scala:260)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$$anonfun$solve$1.apply(TypeConstraints.scala:260)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.util.Collections$class.foreach3(Collections.scala:231)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.foreach3(SymbolTable.scala:16)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$class.solve(TypeConstraints.scala:260)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.solve(SymbolTable.scala:16)   at
>   scala.reflect.internal.Types$ExistentialType.withTypeVars(Types.scala:2699)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.thirdTry$1(TypeComparers.scala:483)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.secondTry$1(TypeComparers.scala:450)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.firstTry$1(TypeComparers.scala:426)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType2(TypeComparers.scala:552)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType1(TypeComparers.scala:320)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType(TypeComparers.scala:278)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.isSubType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.secondTry$1(TypeComparers.scala:445)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.firstTry$1(TypeComparers.scala:426)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType2(TypeComparers.scala:552)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType1(TypeComparers.scala:320)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isSubType(TypeComparers.scala:278)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.isSubType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeComparers$class.isWeakSubType(TypeComparers.scala:575)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.isWeakSubType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.weak_$less$colon$less(Types.scala:825)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Infer$Inferencer$$isCompatible(Infer.scala:305)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer$$anonfun$methTypeArgs$2.apply(Infer.scala:545)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer$$anonfun$methTypeArgs$2.apply(Infer.scala:539)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.util.Collections$class.map2(Collections.scala:79)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.map2(SymbolTable.scala:16)    at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.methTypeArgs(Infer.scala:539)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer$$anonfun$tryInstantiating$1$1.apply$mcZ$sp(Infer.scala:736)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$class.falseIfNoInstance(Infer.scala:114)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.falseIfNoInstance(Global.scala:462)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.tryInstantiating$1(Infer.scala:734)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.typesCompatible$1(Infer.scala:746)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.isApplicableToMethod(Infer.scala:757)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Infer$Inferencer$$isApplicable(Infer.scala:776)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Infer$Inferencer$$isApplicable$2.apply(Infer.scala:778)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Infer$Inferencer$$isApplicable$2.apply(Infer.scala:778)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$class.createFromClonedSymbols(Symbols.scala:3662)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.createFromClonedSymbols(SymbolTable.scala:16)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Infer$Inferencer$$isApplicable(Infer.scala:778)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.checkIsApplicable$1(Infer.scala:807)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.isAsSpecific(Infer.scala:827)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.isStrictlyMoreSpecific(Infer.scala:865)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer$InferMethodAlternativeTwice$1.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Infer$Inferencer$InferMethodAlternativeTwice$$rankAlternatives(Infer.scala:1401)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer$InferMethodAlternativeTwice$1$$anonfun$36.apply(Infer.scala:1404)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer$InferMethodAlternativeTwice$1$$anonfun$36.apply(Infer.scala:1404)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$class.improves$1(Infer.scala:62)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$$anonfun$4.apply(Infer.scala:65)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$$anonfun$4.apply(Infer.scala:65)
>     at scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9.compare(Ordering.scala:200)  at
>   java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)     at
>   scala.collection.SeqLike$class.sorted(SeqLike.scala:648)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractSeq.sorted(Seq.scala:41)     at
>   scala.collection.SeqLike$class.sortWith(SeqLike.scala:601)    at
>   scala.collection.AbstractSeq.sortWith(Seq.scala:41)   at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$class.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Infer$$bestAlternatives(Infer.scala:65)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer$InferMethodAlternativeTwice$1.bestForExpectedType(Infer.scala:1404)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer$InferMethodAlternativeTwice$1.tryOnce(Infer.scala:1416)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context$TryTwice.apply(Contexts.scala:357)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.inferMethodAlternative(Infer.scala:1420)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.handleOverloaded$1(Typers.scala:3297)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.doTypedApply(Typers.scala:3301)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$98.apply(Typers.scala:4496)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$98.apply(Typers.scala:4496)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.tryTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4496)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4544)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.transformedOrTyped(Typers.scala:5605)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedDefDef(Typers.scala:2208)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5308)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3047)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)   at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3151)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1921)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedModuleDef(Typers.scala:1808)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5310)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5452)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3047)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$65.apply(Typers.scala:3151)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:173)   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:189)   at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3151)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5015)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5312)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5359)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5448)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.apply(Analyzer.scala:102)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$applyPhase$1.apply$mcV$sp(Global.scala:440)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.withCurrentUnit(Global.scala:431)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:440)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:94)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:93)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)    at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.run(Analyzer.scala:93)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1501)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1486)   at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1481)  at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1582)     at
>   xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:116)     at
>   xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:95)  at
>   xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:26)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:107)  at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:53)    at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:47)    at
>   sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:74)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:49)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:64)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.IC$$anonfun$compileInternal$1.apply(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
>     at
>   sbt.compiler.IC$$anonfun$compileInternal$1.apply(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
>     at
>   sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:66)
>     at
>   sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:64)
>     at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:32)  at
>   sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:72)    at
>   sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:71)    at
>   sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:99)   at
>   sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:71)    at
>   sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:54)   at
>   sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInternal(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)   at
>   sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)    at
>   sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:155)     at
>   sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:141)     at
>   sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:879)
>     at
>   sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:870)
>     at
>   sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:868)
>     at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)     at
>   sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)    at
>   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)   at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
>     at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
>     at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)   at
>   sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)   at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)    at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)    at
>   sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
>     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [error] (test:compileIncremental)
>   scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: trying to do lub/glb of typevar ?T
>   [error] Total time: 3 s, completed Nov 14, 2016 10:05:52 AM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The create method has got a generic type T and the scala compiler is failing to infer it from the null value you give as a first argument. If you help it a little, it compiles fine:

```
import com.google.common.hash.BloomFilter

object Test {

  def test(): Unit = {
    BloomFilter.create[Nothing](null, 1, 1)
  }

}
```